# TSQL stored proc performance problems with Unions / ORs

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, indexing, query-optimization

I have a static table that I create and build indices on which I then create a stored procedure to run against.  My issue is bizarre and I will do my best to explain it.

I run the same scripts to create and execute across 194 databases...the vast majority of which run very quickly...however on a handful of databases they run exceptionally slow.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DC_GetPotentialDuplicates
    @ID    int,   
    @FirstName  varchar(30),   
    @LastName   varchar(30),   
    @PostalCode varchar(10),
    @YearBorn   varchar(4)    
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   (ID > @ID) AND 
        (
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND FirstName  = @FirstName)  OR
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND PostalCode = @PostalCode) OR
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn)   OR
            (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND PostalCode = @PostalCode) OR  
            (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn)   OR
            (PostalCode = @PostalCode AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn)   
        )
OPTION (RECOMPILE)        
GO
```

This proc consistently runs faster on larger tables...smaller tables "occasionally" run slower.  Speeds range from 4,000-records/second being "fast" down to 70-records/second being "slow".

The thing is if I add in blank filler records to the target table at some point without any other changes the speed increases from 70 upwards closer to the 4,000 mark.  It's as if the query plan is not not being built properly based on the number of records in the table.

To avoid the kluge of adding in blank records to gain speed I rewrote the stored proc to use UNIONS instead of ORs (which generated the same output results)

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DC_GetPotentialDuplicates
    @VoterID    int,   
    @FirstName  varchar(30),   
    @LastName   varchar(30),   
    @PostalCode varchar(10),
    @YearBorn   varchar(4)    
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND FirstName  = @FirstName)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND PostalCode = @PostalCode)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (LastName   = @LastName   AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn) 
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND PostalCode = @PostalCode)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
            (PostalCode = @PostalCode AND YearBorn   = @YearBorn)   
GO
```

Now this stored proc runs just as fast on all the large tables...and increases the speed on about 1/2 of the smaller problematic tables...but only gives me marginal improvement on the remainder.  And again if I increase the record count with blank records on those smaller tables performance improves.

After running both the Database Engine Tuner and Performance monitor it appears to be that the either proc hitting the smaller problem tables are resulting in table scans regardless of forced plans or any optimizations I try.

Any suggestions on what I should be looking at to solve this?

~~~~UPDATED~~~~~
I have narrowed down the issue considerably and it has to do with a missing index that is not missing.

What I have just discovered it that when I re-order the UNION the last one in the list fails to use the INDEX even though it is there.**

In the above code sample I literally swapped the 1st and last unions and now the stored proc does a table scan on LastName and FirstName and the Profiler complains that INDEX is missing.
~~~~~~~~~
**I have created a new question which better defines the problem AND includes a solution located here**

[TSQL UNION ignores INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408789/the-last-union-in-sql-ignores-existing-index)

Comment: Do you UPDATE STATISTICS for small tables on regular basis? Als,o UNION ALL will work faster, if you do not need to filter duplicate rows.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: Are all table _exactly_ the same? Having varchar to nvarchar implicit conversion will result in index scan rahter than seek.

Comment: All the tables are exactly the same as I use the same .sql file.  I recreate the tables from scratch populate them then create the indices.  I have also added in the UPDATE STATISTICS call at the end with no effect.

Comment: Likely, the query plan changed due to different data in the tables. Post both variants of the plan.

Comment: @Stoleg I found that the fastest performance is with a combination of 6-indexes being  (lastname, firstname) (lastname, postalcode) (lastname, yearborn) (firstname, yearborn) (firstname, postalcode) (postalcode, yearborn).  I also have a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index on ID though that makes no difference in performance.

Comment: @usr when you say "plan" do you mean the Estimated Query Plan?  If so plan appears identical on both fast and slow tables.

Comment: @usr I have narrowed the issue down to specifically this: (ugh hit enter).  FAST QUERY: Table 'DC_DuplicateMatch'. Scan count 6, _*logical reads 33*_, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SLOW QUERY: Table 'DC_DuplicateMatch'. Scan count 1, _*logical reads 890*_, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Ok post the actual execution plan, preferably as a .sqlplan file. It's the fastest way to get an insight into whats happening. Could it be that some tables just have data that logically takes longer to process? More rows that qualify maybe?

Comment: It is the data being sent through the stored proc somehow.  I can run both queries back to back one is fast the other slow.  And in the case of the slow one it only uses the clustered index and tables scans all records ignoring the other indexes.

Comment: This is helping thank you.  It appears to be the YearBorn frequency is what is affecting the query plan.  I can edit the query changing only the YearBorn value and it results in either a table scan using only the ID field or a different YearBorn value resulting in the query plan using the other indexes.

Comment: Ok then separate out the YearBorn stuff into a union all (the rest can stay) and add a `WITH (FORCESEEK)` to it.

Comment: Consider using table hint `INDEX` if nothing helps. Def: `INDEX ( index_value [ ,... n ] ) | INDEX = ( index_value )`

Comment: @usr Again thank you very much for your help!  I am now testing which of the 2 suggestions you have given me will have the best performance.  Already my runtime for 6.47-million records across the 194 databases has changed from 1h:36m down to 0h:51m and I hope to improve it further.

Comment: Thinking about it, if you add the 6 perfect indexes for the OR clauses your query should require exactly 6 index seeks at most and the query plan will be very stable. You could even drop the RECOMPILE hint. What indexes do you have? Try creating the 6 perfect indexes (e.g. `FirstName, PostalCode, ID` to name one). You might need to inline the `ID > @ID` into all 6 OR parts.

Comment: @usr I have the 6 indexes (one for each specific UNION including ID as you mentioned) and with the INDEX hints the Query Processor has made a disturbing suggestion.  It says I need to create an index specifically for ([PostalCode],[YearBorn],[ID]) but the problem is I have that exact index and a INDEX hint referencing it.

Comment: I think this is a fun problem. If you create an executable SQL script that I can repro the issue with I'll take a look. Include some test data (maybe by selecting from sys.objects or so).

Comment: @usr problem I have (aside from data privacy issues) is that sample data doesn't work...it seems to be directly related to the number of records in a table.  Smaller and larger tables work fine.  One thing which might not matter I did notice another difference in the Execution Plan.  The "slow" plan lists "Table 'DC_DuplicateMatch'. Scan count 6, logical reads 425, ... Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0"  HOWEVER the "fast" plan says "Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, ... Table 'DC_DuplicateMatch'. Scan count 6, logical reads 34" -The tables are in different order

Comment: @usr OK I have streamlined it and will try to send what you asked for.  I have stripped out everything and will edit the question above to show you while I get what you asked for together.

Comment: I started a new "question" to better explain what I have come across  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408789/the-last-union-in-sql-ignores-existing-index

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking every permutation, you could count the duplicates:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch
WHERE   (ID > @ID) AND 
        (
                CASE [LastName]   WHEN @LastName   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE [FirstName]  WHEN @FirstName  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE [PostalCode] WHEN @PostalCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE [YearBorn]   WHEN @YearBorn   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) >= 2
```