# The last UNION in SQL ignores existing INDEX

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, indexing, query-optimization, union

This is a refined problem I have been struggling with for a couple of days now.

I have a static table that I create and build indexes on which I then create a stored procedure to run against. My issue is bizarre and I will do my best to explain it.

I run the same scripts to create and execute across 194 databases...the vast majority of which run very quickly...however on a handful of databases they run exceptionally slow.

Just so we are clear here are the INDEX:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_ID
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID)
go
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_FirstName
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, LastName, FirstName)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_PostalCode
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, LastName, PostalCode)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, LastName, YearBorn)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName_PostalCode 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, FirstName, PostalCode)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, FirstName, YearBorn)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_PostalCode_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(ID, PostalCode, YearBorn)
GO
```

And here is the the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DC_GetPotentialDuplicates
    @ID    int,   
    @FirstName  varchar(30),   
    @LastName   varchar(30),   
    @PostalCode varchar(10),
    @YearBorn   varchar(4)    
AS
SELECT *  
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_LastName_FirstName))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (LastName   = @LastName   AND 
        FirstName  = @FirstName)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_LastName_PostalCode))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (LastName   = @LastName   AND 
        PostalCode = @PostalCode)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_LastName_YearBorn))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (LastName   = @LastName   AND 
        YearBorn   = @YearBorn)
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_FirstName_PostalCode))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND 
        PostalCode = @PostalCode)
UNION            
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_FirstName_YearBorn))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (FirstName  = @FirstName  AND 
        YearBorn   = @YearBorn)
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    DC_DuplicateMatch WITH(INDEX(IX_PostalCode_YearBorn))
WHERE   ID > @ID AND 
        (PostalCode = @PostalCode AND 
        YearBorn   = @YearBorn)
GO
```

Table Definition

```
ID          int no  4  10   0   
FirstName   varchar no  30              
LastName    varchar no  30          
PostalCode  char    no  10          
YearBorn    varchar no  4
```

This proc consistently runs faster on larger tables...smaller tables "occasionally" run slower. Speeds range from 4,000-records/second being "fast" down to 70-records/second being "slow".

The thing is if I add in blank filler records to the target table at some point, without any other changes, the speed increases from 70 upwards closer to the 4,000 mark. It's as if the query plan is not not being built properly based on the number of records in the table.

After running both the Database Engine Tuner and Performance Monitor I have discovered the problem is SQL ignores the INDEX on the last UNION and does a table scan on **some** queries.  And the Execution Plan specifically says I need to create the exact index I already have on the table (hence the INDEX Hints).

*So I removed the 6th select UNION*

The issue remained; however this time it complained that the missing index was again on the last table of the unions (which is the 5th listed above and worked without issue when there where 6-select UNIONS).

Any thoughts on why this is happening or what I can do to avoid it?  (aside from adding in dummy blank records to increase table size or creating a fake 7th final union...both of which increase performance).

Comment: Can you add the table definition? I must be able to run the code and play with it because just looking at it I was unable to help you in the last question.

Comment: Ah it suddenly occurred to me why the obvious index is not always being used: it is not covering. Test this idea by either a) do a `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *` or b) by making all indexes fully covering (`INCLUDE (...)`).

Comment: I added in the SELECT 1 and the Execution Plan still complained about a missing index on the last SELECT.  I am not sure what you mean about the "index not covering" or how to use the INCLUDE option but will look that up now.  I will also add the table definition to the above question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing indexes aren't that good because `ID` is the leading column. That makes them unseekable in this case. Here's a better set:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_FirstName
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(LastName, FirstName, ID) INCLUDE (PostalCode, YearBorn)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_PostalCode
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(LastName, PostalCode, ID) INCLUDE (FirstName, YearBorn)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(LastName, YearBorn, ID) INCLUDE (FirstName, PostalCode)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName_PostalCode 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(FirstName, PostalCode, ID) INCLUDE (LastName, YearBorn)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(FirstName, YearBorn, ID) INCLUDE (LastName, PostalCode)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_PostalCode_YearBorn 
ON DC_DuplicateMatch(PostalCode, YearBorn, ID) INCLUDE (LastName, FirstName)
GO
```

These are perfect for this query.

[image]

That's 6 index seeks per query. We'd need to pull some serious tricks to beat this.

Comment: I will try this the moment I get into work but your plan clearly solved the problem (cool graphic insert).  Originally I had not referenced ID in the indexes but I do see your point.  I have not used INCLUDE before but I am confused as to why i would INCLUDE the same two fields as my basic index contains.   Something i will have to research and again thank you very much for all your help :)

Comment: The INCLUDE is there so that SQL Server can read the entire row from the index. Without the INCLUDE it would have to insert a key-lookup for each row. This is what drove SQL Server to use the table scan instead because it thought that many rows would be coming back.

Comment: @usr, Good solution! Why `ID` is the last column? Also, AFAIK, clustered index column is appended to non-clustrerd index columns, so those indexes look like `(ID, LastName, FirstName, ID)`, which is strange. And 3d question: why to use `INCLUDE` instead of making a covering indexes?

Comment: @Stoleg ID is last because it has an inequality predicate (ID > @ID). Only one inequality can be served from an index, at the last position. The CI columns are appended, true. Only if not already present. (LastName, FirstName) would have been enough but (LastName, FirstName, ID) documents our intent better. Makes no difference to the machine, just to the human. 3) I'm not sure what the difference would be in terms of SQL Server behavior. In any case it is small. I like to use INCLUDE to document that these columns are not meant to be seeked on. I like self-documenting code.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most of the time when the query planner doesn't use an appropriate index its because update statistics needs to be rerun to have the optimizer work correctly. This seems symptomatic of the fact that your query plan is bad for just some values.

Since you're providing an index hint though, this seems unlikely- normally a hint would force the planner to use that index, but maybe that depends on your vendor.

Comment: I have used both UPDATE STATISTICS and OPTION(RECOMPILE) to no avail.

Comment: Is the query optimizer giving you an expected join order?

This is a reach, but as a general rule indexes don't provide a performance gain over table scans if you're returning more than 20% of a tables contents. I wonder if its possible that the ID resultset you're searching for is returning so many rows that the optimizer is skipping all the indexes and going straight to disk to pull all of those rows once into cache then make use of your clustered index (but I would probably expect to see some hint of this in your query plan).

Comment: I wonder if your cache size plays into this- since you're seeing small tables take more time than large tables to query. Are these smaller tables as active (hot) as your big tables? Its possible that the indexes are being knocked out of cache if they aren't explicitly bound and don't often get placed back in because they are being queried as often. 

This may be a red herring though since when you remove the final UNION the previous UNION then table scans. I'm not really sure how to interpret that in relation to the cache size.

Comment: I have ~6.5-Million records across 194-databases without indexes my performance is around 70-records/second as a result of constant table scans.  With indexes I am able to do over 4,000-records/second.  Having said that the largest data set I get returned is upwards of 1,000 records and it does seem that there is a trigger of sorts in there that causes it to do a table scan when that happens.  Having said that as I mentioned if I add blank dummy records into the target table then this issue disappears...

Comment: Sorry I cant be more concrete, this is a pretty weird problem.

Comment: Just a check: if you remove the hints I take it you get the same table scan problems? Giving hints to the optimizer usually does more harm than good.

Comment: Cache should not be an issue as I am the only one accessing these tables one after the other and the moment I hit them they should be loaded into ram.

Comment: Ya I was reluctant to use the hints as well and I originally did not have them.  But when I found the Execution Plan complaining about it I added them in...did not make any difference mind you...but equally did no harm so I left them for now.